# Does "on a diet" mean cut down meat?

Tags: meaning

What does "on a diet" mean?

Does "on a diet" only mean to lose weight, or just eating a special kind of food (like eating a lot of meat or just eat vegetables)?

Comment: The meaning is very easy to find online https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on+a+diet%22&client=ms-android-samsung&sxsrf=ALiCzsZbyGK8Sv8Pk64ietjFOdyNUSZ-Dw%3A1651984074237&ei=ykZ3YtSUDraGxc8P-O6z8As&oq=%22on+a+diet%22&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAMyBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeOgcIIxCwAxAnOgcIABBHELADOgQIABBDOgUIABCABEoECEEYAFDcGFjcK2C-N2gBcAF4AIABe4gB3wGSAQMwLjKYAQCgAQHIAQnAAQE&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp

Comment: on a diet means, as is easy to find, e.g. https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+a+diet, following a particular diet, possibly with the objective of loosing weight, but not necessarily

Answer (score 11):

*On a diet*, on its own, usually means a diet that is intended to help the dieter lose weight.

It could refer to any other special diet, but normally, if that is the intention, the word will be qualified. (eg *on a low-carb diet*, *on a paleo diet* etc).

Comment: "On a special diet", "on a certain diet", or similar is often used to indicate a restricted diet other than a weight-loss program, without being specific about which one.

Answer (score 6):

‘on a diet’ with no further qualifiers normally implies that the person being discussed has restricted what foods they eat to achieve some medical benefit. *Usually*, without context to imply otherwise, the desired medical benefit is weight loss.

‘special diet’ may sometimes be used in place of ‘diet’ to indicate that the desired medical benefit is something other than weight loss (for example, lowering blood pressure) when the speaker does not wish to specify an exact type of diet.

Other qualifiers may be used in a similar way to indicate a particular type of diet, which may or may not be targeted at weight loss. Common examples include:

- 'low carb diet': Reduced carbohydrate content, one common type of low calorie diet used for weight loss.
- ‘low fat diet’: Reduced fat content, typically used to aid in weight loss or reduce risk of cardiovascular problems.
- 'low sodium diet': Reduced salt content, typically used to help manage high blood pressure.
- ‘gluten-free diet’: No gluten (a protein complex found in many common cereal grains), formally used to help treat wheat allergies and some forms of IBS as well as the gastrointestinal symptoms of some autoimmune disorders, sometimes used (with no medical evidence to support it) to attempt to treat other things.
- ‘paleolithic diet’ (or ‘paleo diet’): No processed foods, intended to mimic the dietary practices of ancient humans, supposedly improves overall health but the actual benefits based on observational data range from minimal to nonexistent and it increases the risk of certain types of malnutrition (especially low calcium intake).
- ‘vegetarian diet’: No meat. Required by certain eastern or middle eastern religions, used elsewhere because of perceived health benefits or due to a moral objection to the consumption of meat. May or may not include certain non-meat animal products (eggs and dairy products are the primary points of contention).
- ‘vegan diet’: No meat and no animal products of any form. Usually a matter of philosophy, though some vegans may quote health benefits. May or may not extend to other aspects of life, may or may not consider insect byproducts (honey, silk, etc) as acceptable, some extreme vegan diets even disallow fermented foods and bread (because of the use of yeast). Requires very specific nutritional planning to avoid malnourishment.
- ‘pescetarian diet’: No meat other than seafood. Usually used as a practical compromise between vegetarianism and whatever the local cuisine is (it’s actually pretty hard to be a vegetarian in some parts of the world and stay healthy simply due to the availability of various ingredients).
- ‘pollotarian diet’: Same concept as pescetarianism, just with poultry instead of seafood. Similarly typically a compromise between vegetarianism and whatever the local cuisine is.
- ‘kosher diet’: A diet following Jewish dietary laws (kashrut), includes special restrictions both on what can be consumed and also how the ingredients must be handled.
- ‘halal diet’: A diet following Islamic dietary laws, includes special restrictions both on what can be consumed and how the ingredients must be handled.

Depending on the situation, many people will instead simply list what they cannot eat. This is especially common for people with food allergies, which are often specific enough to simply quote a single food or category of food that is off-limits.

Answer (score 1):

If you say you are *on a diet*, it doesn't necessarily mean you are cutting down on meat or increasing your intake of vegetables. It means you are trying to lose weight, which could be for health reasons or because you want to be/look slimmer.

Lexico, formerly Oxford Dictionaries, in its second definition of the word **diet** says

> **2** [A special course of food to which a person restricts themselves, either to lose weight or for medical reasons](https://www.lexico.com/definition/diet).
>
> ‘I'm going **on a diet**’
> ‘Some people do lose weight **on low-carb diets**, but the weight loss probably isn't related to blood sugar and insulin levels.’

Merriam-Webster says “on a diet" is an idiom, and defines it as

> ***[on a diet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20a%20diet)*** : eating less food or only particular kinds of food in order to lose weight.